# How to list a newtonsoft Jtoken or JObjects children in a listBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, listbox, json.net

I have a json file that i read to string and then convert to a jobject. I get a JToken from this object by selecting one of its children.

I want to list this JTokens children in a Listbox. I think, to do this i need to convert th eJTOken to a ListItem - how can i do this? If there is a better alternative way then would be interested to hear it!

```
    string filePath = @"C:\output.json";
    JObject json = JObject.Parse(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath));
    JToken jsonFiles = json["Files"];
    jsonFilesListItem = ....

    JsonListBox.Items.Add(jsonFilesListItem);
```

Comment: Are these children simply of type `string` that you want to display?

Comment: yes, i just want to display the children strings. If there is a way of getting both th ekey and value in separate varables then great, if not then get both to a string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that `json["Files"]` contains a simple array of strings, all you have to do is use a foreach loop, as shown in the example below:

```
string jsonString = @"
{
    ""Files"": [
        ""foo.xml"",
        ""bar.txt"",
        ""baz.jpg"",
        ""quux.wav""
    ]
}";

JObject json = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
JToken jsonFiles = json["Files"];

foreach (string fileName in jsonFiles)
{
    JsonListBox.Items.Add(fileName);
}
```

Comment: How would you do the same without `foreach` using LINQ?

Comment: @JariTurkia If you wanted to use LINQ you could do something like this: `JsonListBox.Items.AddRange(json["Files"].Select(jt=>(string)jt).ToArray());`  But it would depend on what kind of ListBox you were talking about.  The foregoing would work for WinForms, but for an Asp.Net ListBox you would need to change the `Select` statement to wrap each string in a new `ListItem`.